# Certificate error while connecting to MQ through HermesJMS

Tags: ssl, soapui, mq, hermes-jms

I am not very much familiar with HermesJMS.

I have HermesJMS configured to connect some MQs sometime back and it was working fine. then I stopped using it. Now I am trying to connect to the same set of MQs, I am getting below error.

```
com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code 2, Reason 2397
at com.ibm.mq.MQManagedConnectionJ11.<init>(MQManagedConnectionJ11.java:282)
at com.ibm.mq.MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11._createManagedConnection(MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:301)
at com.ibm.mq.MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.createManagedConnection(MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:323)
at com.ibm.mq.StoredManagedConnection.<init>(StoredManagedConnection.java:84)
at com.ibm.mq.MQSimpleConnectionManager.allocateConnection(MQSimpleConnectionManager.java:173)
at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.obtainBaseMQQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:795)
at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.procure(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:709)
at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.constructQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:664)
at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.createQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:160)
at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager.<init>(MQQueueManager.java:554)
at com.ibm.mq.MQSPIQueueManager.<init>(MQSPIQueueManager.java:62)
at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnection.createQM(MQConnection.java:2513)
at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnection.createQMNonXA(MQConnection.java:1936)
at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnection.<init>(MQQueueConnection.java:161)
at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:222)
at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.createConnection(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:1077)
at hermes.impl.jms.ConnectionManagerSupport.createConnection(ConnectionManagerSupport.java:126)
at hermes.impl.jms.ConnectionSharedManager.reconnect(ConnectionSharedManager.java:77)
at hermes.impl.jms.ThreadLocalSessionManager.reconnect(ThreadLocalSessionManager.java:148)
at hermes.impl.DefaultHermesImpl.reconnect(DefaultHermesImpl.java:130)
at hermes.impl.DefaultHermesImpl.getDestination(DefaultHermesImpl.java:364)
at hermes.browser.tasks.BrowseDestinationTask.invoke(BrowseDestinationTask.java:141)
at hermes.browser.tasks.TaskSupport.run(TaskSupport.java:175)
at hermes.browser.tasks.ThreadPool.run(ThreadPool.java:170)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.mq.SSLHelper.configureSSLSocket(SSLHelper.java:768)
at com.ibm.mq.SSLHelper.createSSLSocket(SSLHelper.java:154)
at com.ibm.mq.MQInternalCommunications.createSocketConnection(MQInternalCommunications.java:2335)
at com.ibm.mq.MQv6InternalCommunications$1.run(MQv6InternalCommunications.java:169)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.ibm.mq.MQv6InternalCommunications.initialize(MQv6InternalCommunications.java:166)
at com.ibm.mq.MQv6InternalCommunications.<init>(MQv6InternalCommunications.java:114)
at com.ibm.mq.MQSESSIONClient.MQCONNX(MQSESSIONClient.java:1458)
at com.ibm.mq.MQSESSIONClient.spiConnect(MQSESSIONClient.java:4610)
at com.ibm.mq.MQManagedConnectionJ11.<init>(MQManagedConnectionJ11.java:246)
... 24 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
... 42 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
... 48 more
```

I know this is something to do with the certificate as it is giving SSLHandshakeException, but I am not pretty sure where I should be checking the configuration. 
As per my knowledge there is no change in the configuration. (I can't be sure about it as MQs are managed by a different team and they don't bother to communicate the changes to rest of the world).

How can I verify and confirm if it is the certificate issue and no other configuration problem.

Comment: Don't know if it will help, but try this: https://siking.wordpress.com/2016/02/18/another-way-to-fix-sslhandshakeexception-in-soapui/

Comment: I tried that but did not help.. In fact after renaming the directory and restarting the HermesJMS, all my previous configuration is lost :(

Answer (score 0):

If you doesn't change nothing in your configuration the most probably thing is that the service endpoint change or renew its server domain certificate and due this it's not a trusted certificate for your configuration anymore.

To solve the problem you need to add the *certificate authority* in your *truststore* (or directly the server domain certificate for a selfsigned certs).

SOAPUI it's Java based, and Java comes with its own *truststore*. The good practice is to add the *CA* certificates to your *truststore* (however it's possible to only add the server certificate). You can add it using [`keytool`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html) with the follow command:

`keytool -import -alias <someAlias> -file <certificatePath> -keystore <trustStorePath>`

Depends on your *SOAPUI* installation the *truststore* location can differs, if you have a *JRE* bundled inside *SOAPUI* then your truststore are in `SOAPUI_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts` if not, then is in your *Java* installation which runs *SOAPUI* in `$JAVA_HOME/JRE/Security/cacerts` (default password for both are `changeit`).

Hope it helps,